# OK to add this as a Listener inside constructor of final class if single threaded?

Tags: java, constructor, this, listener, final

I inherited a large Swing application.  Consider this bare bones version of its GUI's main window class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

final class ListenerExample1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private final JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
    private int clickCount = 0;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( () -> {
            ListenerExample1 instance = new ListenerExample1();
            instance.setVisible(true);
            instance.pack();
        } );
    }

    ListenerExample1() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) throw new IllegalStateException("the current thread (" + Thread.currentThread().toString() + ") is not EventQueue's dispatch thread");

        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) throw new IllegalStateException("the current thread (" + Thread.currentThread().toString() + ") is not EventQueue's dispatch thread");

        markButtonAsClicked();
    }

    void markButtonAsClicked() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) throw new IllegalStateException("the current thread (" + Thread.currentThread().toString() + ") is not EventQueue's dispatch thread");

        button.setText("click #" + (++clickCount));
    }

}
```

This code is stripped down 100 times from the actual application to achieve a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

IntelliJ correctly warns me that this line

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

is causing the this reference to escape during construction.

I am fully aware of why this is usually a bad thing.  This is discussed at length in "The Bible", [Java Concurrency In Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com).  Some dedicated articles by Goetz on this topic are [Safe construction techniques](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0618/) and [Be a good (event) listener](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07265/).

**However, is it actually bad in this case?**

In particular, note that this class should only ever be touched by a single thread.  That is because of the rule that [Swing components must only be touched by EventQueue's dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading) (the "EDT").  So, the main method uses SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait, and the constructor and instance methods all check that the calling thread is the EDT.

Also, note that this class is final, which rules out subclass issues.

*So, I think that the code above is actually safe, despite IntelliJ's warning, but I want to know if I have overlooked some subtle problem.*

There are reasons, not obvious in the simplified code above, why I want to add this as a Listener in several constructors of my actual application.

Speaking of IntelliJ, I note that the code above can be simplified.  Instead of having the class implements ActionListener, which therefore exposes the actionPerformed method for no good reason, you can use a lambda to implicitly create an instance inner class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

final class ListenerExample2 extends JFrame {

    private final JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
    private int clickCount = 0;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait( () -> {
            ListenerExample2 instance = new ListenerExample2();
            instance.setVisible(true);
            instance.pack();
        } );
    }

    ListenerExample2() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) throw new IllegalStateException("the current thread (" + Thread.currentThread().toString() + ") is not EventQueue's dispatch thread");

        add(button);
        button.addActionListener( (e) -> markButtonAsClicked() );
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    void markButtonAsClicked() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) throw new IllegalStateException("the current thread (" + Thread.currentThread().toString() + ") is not EventQueue's dispatch thread");

        button.setText("click #" + (++clickCount));
    }

}
```

To my surprise, IntelliJ does not warn that this new lambda line

```
button.addActionListener( (e) -> markButtonAsClicked() );
```

is once again causing the this reference to escape during construction--and this line most certainly does let the this escape!

*Is this just a defect in IntelliJ's inspection code?*

Or is there some subtle reason why the lambda code actually is safe in general?  (This new lambda code should be safe in this particular case for the same reasons discussed above for the original version.)